# Surfing in Sri Lanka in August

Tags: sri-lanka, surfing

We're headed to Sri Lanka for surfing in August and all the websites I've read mention the East Coast/Arugam Bay for this time off the year and do not mention others at all.

Is it the only availabe surf spot in the country this year? Or is it just that it's the best one and we could also go to other spots (particularly on the west coast), that might just not have as great waves?

Comment: Have you heard about monsoon? If not, Sri Lanka has two monsoon seasons. https://www.lonelyplanet.com/sri-lanka/weather  August is not the best time for Surfing.

Comment: I have heard about it, but all the sources said that the monsoon during that time does mainly affect the West or inland and not the East Coast, and that August is peak season for surfing in Arugam Bay (e.g. [here](https://magicseaweed.com/Arugam-Bay-Surf-Guide/562/), or [here](https://www.surftravel.com.au/destinations/sri-lanka-surf-holiday/east-coast/arugam-bay/)

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for Sri Lanka surf returns myriad, first person accounts

- [Surf South Sri Lanka](https://www.surfsouthsrilanka.com/)
- [The Best Surf Spots in Sri Lanka](https://theculturetrip.com/asia/sri-lanka/articles/the-best-surf-spots-in-sri-lanka/)
- [Surf Team Sri Lanka Surf Teams](http://www.surfteamsrilanka.com/surf-clubs-in-sri-lanka-3/)
- [The 10 Best Surfing Spots in Sri Lanka for a Tropical Adventure](https://www.booksurfcamps.com/news/surfing-sri-lanka)

[WannaSurf Sri Lanka Surf Spots](https://www.wannasurf.com/spot/Asia/Sri_Lanka/) lists 37 surf spots, rating them for wave quality, direction, type, frequency, and experience, along with an interactive map and on seasonal swell and wind variations.